# How to stream a Twilio voice call directly to Google voice API instantly

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

I am doubtful about implementing a feature in my python application. I am using Twilio's python SDK for call handling and response. When a Twilio call is placed, I want a functionality where the caller's speech is directly streamed to Google Voice API for text transciption **during the call itself**. And then I need to process the transcribed text to provide appropriate responses to the user instantly.

I am aware of the **Record** feature in twilio which helps us record the caller's voice and save them as recordings. One way would be to access the recording file once it is available and then pass the recorded file to Google API. But I feel this way would be slower since I need the caller's voice streamed instantly to Google voice API.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i want to do the same thing you are doing

Comment: @FightFireWithFire Nope. I went with the native voice transcription provided by Twilio. As answered below, Twilio doesn't provide live streaming of the voice call to another API. A drawback though, for someone who is looking to implement advanced functionalities!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can actually do this within Twilio these days. Using the [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) TwiML verb with the [`input` attribute set to "speech"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#attributes-input) Twilio will play your audio through the Google Voice API to live transcribe it.

You can get the results of the transcription by setting the [`action` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#attributes-action) to a URL in your application. When Twilio and Google have detected and transcribed the speech, Twilio will make a webhook to the URL with the transcribed text sent as a `SpeechResult` parameter in the request body.

You cannot get the raw audio from the call yourself though, so this is the best way to achieve what you are trying to build.

Comment: Thanks for that @philnash. But the twilio documentation says using the "speech" attribute is chargeable. Is there any other way out without charges?

Comment: There's no way to pipe the audio directly to Google Voice, that's what `<Gather input="speech">` does. You could do it the way you suggested with the recording, but as you say, that will take more time. Notably the Google Voice API isn't free either (though there is a free trial).

Comment: and one more question. Does the "speech" attribute of twilio use the Google voice transcription in the backend, without having the need to set up a separate google voice api call in my application using the speech input gathered ?

Comment: That’s correct, it does that and just returns the detected speech in the Webhook.

Comment: Lovely. Thanks!

Comment: Still input=speech uses Google voice API or Twilio have changed it to native Twilio transcription ? If it changed, suggest me a way to achieve voice transcription through Google !

Comment: As far as I’m aware it uses Google’s voice API.

Comment: Could you please try it and confirm ? As far as my study and trails i understand that input=speech uses native Twilio transcription and the quality is not up to Google API. Please suggest me a way to achieve better transcriptions.

Comment: As far as I know we still use the Google Cloud Speech API, with the data set trained on phone calls (that is, audio downsampled to 8khz). I can’t test this right now because I’m on holiday. If you have concerns about this I recommend you get in touch with Twilio support.

Comment: If they use Google API to transcribe, where do we set the Google credentials?

Comment: @masterFly you don't need to set any Google credentials, it is done through a Twilio integration.

Comment: I don't think this is true. I tried saying the same sentence to google directly and to Gather command. Both gave me 2 different results. And also Twilio does not say anything on Google integration on their documentation. Bit confused though!

Comment: The Google integration should be seamless to you and it's not necessarily important that it is Google. Also, currently because Twilio audio is over the phone we use the [phone model](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics#select-model) from Google's text to speech so you may find different results.

Comment: It is important because Google transcription is more accurate. Let me check for for information as well. Thank you @philnash

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Record timeout="10" transcribe="true" />
</Response>
```

Python Code:

 `SDK Version: 6.x`
 `from twilio.twiml.voice_response import Record, VoiceResponse

response = VoiceResponse()
response.record(timeout=10, transcribe=True)

print(response)

It's built into twilio already.  Why use google voice api to transcribe, you can just redirect using anything to send this as an email from a specific service account and build a label or filter for these emails to catalog or segregate them into their own folder.

I might be missing what you're doing altogether but you can use the record function in a response right after dial and set transcribe to true.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record

Comment: I am already aware of this functionality you stated. But twilio charges for all transcriptions. Moreover, I find google to be accurate enough when compared to the native twilio transcription. All i want is to stream the voice of the caller directly to the Google voice API, instead of passing the recording file after the recording is finished.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

New updates on TwiML will help you for this solution.
The new **TwiML stream** command streams call audio to a websocket server.

This makes it simple to move your call audio from your business phone system into an AI platform that can transcribe that data in real time with with **Google Cloud’s Speech-to-Text using Twilio’s Media Streams.**

Go through the documentation on below link

[Google Speech to text Twilio Integration](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/partners/using-google-cloud-speech-to-text-to-transcribe-your-twilio-calls-in-real-time)

**Solution 2:**

Even the better solution that I found is Twilio provides Add-On features that provide better support for analyzing the incoming data.

You can use **IBM-Watson Speech to text Add-on** helps you to understand your **Twilio** Phone voice better.

Please look in to the official documentation below by twilio:

[IBM Watson Speech to text Twilio Integration](https://www.twilio.com/docs/add-ons/tutorials/how-to-use-recordings-add-ons-in-python#using-add-on-data-in-your-application)